# How to split the string in a single column and arrange the same in the same column in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column as below

```
Products
jeans,oil
jeans,shampoo
```

I want to split the strings and use it in the same column using SQL. The result I want is

```
Products  count
jeans     2
oil       1
shampoo   1
```

Could you please guide me in getting this result

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Turning a Comma Separated string into individual rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493510/turning-a-comma-separated-string-into-individual-rows)

Comment: similar answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17942691/2750968

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are storing CSV data in your SQL table, which is not a good thing.  But it looks like you are trying to move away from that, which is a good thing.  Here is one option using a union with `SUBSTRING_INDEX`:

```
SELECT Products, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM
(
    SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(Products, ',', 1) AS Products FROM yourTable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(Products, ',', -1) FROM yourTable
) t
GROUP BY Products
ORDER BY
    count DESC, Products;
```

[image]

### Demo

Comment: assuming column "products" has only one comma separated value., ex: jeans,oil
 this doesn't work if it has three values "jeans,oil,conditioner"

Comment: Is this using MYSQL ? When I tried this in w3schools SQL, it is showing no such function like substring_index. Could you please tell me if there is an alternative to this substring_index?

Comment: @SrihariRaghu Check the demo, there most certainly is a `SUBSTRING_INDEX`.  Maybe your demo sight is using some really archaic version of MySQL which does not have this function.

Comment: Thank you for the demo and your answer. ... Yes as ManiDeep said, if I add one more value to the product name, it is taking the first and last index. It is not considering the intermediate values

Comment: To handle arbitrary numbers of CSV data you'll need to write a UDF or a stored proc.  This has been handled already in other questions.  I only answered based on the data you showed us.  _Don't_ store CSV like this if you can avoid it.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. :)  made my day with your demo and answer as well

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you need to split the data into two columns like

```
    SELECT CASE
     WHEN name LIKE '%,%' THEN LEFT(name, Charindex(' ', products) - 1)
     ELSE name
   END,
   CASE
     WHEN name LIKE '%,%' THEN RIGHT(name, Charindex(' ', Reverse(products)) - 1)
   END
   FROM   YourTable
```

then you need to union this with the same table... and the final code will look like...

```
    select count( distinct abc), abc from 
    (
    SELECT CASE
       WHEN PA_NAME LIKE '% %' THEN LEFT(PA_NAME, Charindex(' ', PA_NAME) - 1)
       ELSE PA_NAME
    END [abc]
    FROM   phparty

    union all

    SELECT CASE
     WHEN PA_NAME LIKE '% %' THEN RIGHT(PA_NAME, Charindex(' ', Reverse(PA_NAME)) -1)
   END [abc]
    FROM   phparty
    ) t group by abc
```

here you can replace pa_name with your_column_name

Comment: Hi Amrita, Thank you for the answer. But I will go with Tim's answer which looks easier to me.

Comment: `charIndex` is not supported in `mysql`

Comment: you can use locate() or substring_index() for mysql